# Is a Django model with parents that have a parent and child relationship among them?

Tags: django, django-models

To elaborate, I wish to set up a model where a blog post can have a like and a comment on the post can also be liked.

I could build two models, post_like and comment_like where they would both be children of blog post and comment respectively. Is there a way through which I could implement the above functionality with a single model? Something more generic. Where 1 model can be used to implement the like functionality?

```
class Like(models.Model):
      post = models.ForeignKey(post..., default = None)
      comment = models. ForeignKey(comment...default = None)
      like_type = models.CharField(choices, default = None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field on `models` called `GenericForeignKey` for that.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations